# How can I check if a value is numeric, alphabetical or alphanumeric in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have array which values are user input like:

```
aa df rrr5 4323 54 hjy 10 gj @fgf %d
```

Now I want to check each value in array to see whether it's numeric, alphabetic (a-zA-Z), or alphanumeric and save them in other respective arrays.

I have done:

```
my @num;
my @char;
my @alphanum;

my $str =<>;
  my @temp = split(" ",$str);
        foreach (@temp)
           {
                print "input : $_ \n";
                if ($_ =~/^(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)$/)
                    {
                        push(@num,$_);
                    }
           }
```

This works. Similarly I want to check for alphabet, and alphanumeric values

Alphanumeric example are: `fr43`  `6t$` `$eed5` `*jh`

Comment: The answer you accepted doesn't produce the results which you claim to want in your question. Specifically, the POSIX character class [:alphanum:] will not match punctuation characters meaning that 6t$ $eed5 *jh will not be matched.  See my updated answer below.

Comment: @Robert S. Barnes : yes you are right i wasn't paying enough attention on my requirements sorry for that..and thanks for making me realize that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you accepted doesn't produce the results which you claim to want in your question.  Specifically, the `POSIX` character class `[:alphanum:]` will not match punctuation characters meaning that **6t$ $eed5 *jh** will not be matched.  In order to match punctuation characters you need to add `[:punct:]` to the char class.  See the [Regex cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/).

So for example if you have the file tokens.txt which contains:

> aa df rrr5 4323 54 hjy 10 gj @fgf %d fr43 6t$ $eed5 *jh

And you run this perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use strict;
use Scalar::Util qw( looks_like_number );


my $str =<>;
my @temp = split(" ",$str);

my @num = grep { looks_like_number($_) } @temp;
my @char = grep /^[[:alpha:]]+$/, @temp;
my @alphanum = grep /^[[:alnum:][:punct:]]+$/, @temp;

print "Numbers: " . join(' ', @num) . "\n";
print "Alpha: " . join(' ', @char) . "\n";
print "Alphanum: " . join(' ', @alphanum) . "\n";
```

like this:

```
cat tokens.txt | ./tokenize.pl
```

You get the output:

> Numbers: 4323 54 10
>   Alpha: aa df hjy gj
>   Alphanum: aa df rrr5 4323 54 hjy 10 gj @fgf %d fr43 6t$ $eed5 *jh

However, it seems by your question that you don't want to match all punctuation characters such as `@` and `%`, but instead only certain ones such as `$` and `*`.

If that's the case then you just change the Alphanum match to:

```
my @alphanum = grep /^[[:alnum:]\$\*]+$/, @temp;
```

Which will then give you the desired output of

> Numbers: 4323 54 10
>   Alpha: aa df hjy gj
>   Alphanum: aa df rrr5 4323 54 hjy 10 gj fr43 6t$ $eed5 *jh

Answer (score 8):

Perl supports POSIX character classes, so you can actually do this:

```
$string =~ /^[[:alpha:]]+$/;
$string =~ /^[[:alnum:]]+$/;
```

Numbers are less well defined, but Scalar::Util's [looks_like_number](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar::Util#looks_like_number) function may do  what you want it to do.

Comment: ? that checks whether string is a single alpha or alnum character (possibly with a following \n)

Answer (score 1):

For separating the input into arrays something like this would work and allow easy additions or changes to your matches.

```
my $input = 'aa df rrr5 4323 54 hjy 10 gj @fgf %d';
my %tests = ( 
    num   => '\d+',
    alpha => '[[:alpha:]]+', 
    alnum => '[[:alnum:]]+' 
);

my %res;
for my $t (keys %tests) {
    for (split(' ', $input)) {
        push(@{ $res{$t} }, $_) if (/^$tests{$t}$/i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alphabet:

```
 /^[a-z]+$/i
```

What most people mean by alphanumeric:

```
 /^[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

**BUT WAIT:**

> note: alphanumeric ex. fr43 6t$ $eed5 *jh

I didn't understand this, but judging from your comment below and the quote above, what you mean by alphanumeric might be achieved by

```
 /^[[:graph:]]+$/
```

That matches any printable ASCII characters except spaces.

Hope this has solved your problem.

Comment: @Kinopiko: note was to indicate special characters are in alphanumeric and not in alphabetic

Comment: I took that as anything that isn't numeric or alphabetic gets classified as alphanumeric, regardless of what characters there are.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recognize all valid numbers (scientific/fixed/... notation), you can let Perl do the work like this:

```
sub test_num {
    no warnings "all";
    $b = "$_[0]"; 
    $a = $b + 0; 
    return ($a eq $b);
}
push(@num, $tmp) if (test_num($tmp));
```

(The reason for the line `$b = "$_[0]";` is that otherwise the original variable - `$tmp` - is brought into numeric context inside `test_num` function - a bit of undesired side-effect)